# No definition for ToList

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm trying to use Linq to read a CSV (each line has the components of a `DailyValues` object) and put all of the objects into a `List`.  Without `ToList()` it gives `cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable to List` and if I put the `.ToList()` on there it says that `decimal does contain a definition for ToList()`.   For the record, I am `using System.Linq`.  How can I use the following to convert the data in the CSV into my list of objects?

```
        List<DailyValues> values = new List<DailyValues>();

        values = from line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Skip(1)
                 let columns = line.Split(',')
                 select new DailyValues
                 {
                     Date = DateTime.Parse(columns[0]),
                     Open = decimal.Parse(columns[1]),
                     High = decimal.Parse(columns[2]),
                     Low = decimal.Parse(columns[3]),
                     Close = decimal.Parse(columns[4]),
                     Volume = decimal.Parse(columns[5]),
                     AdjClose = decimal.Parse(columns[6])
                     .ToList()  // this guy is the problem
                 };
```

Comment: `decimal` does not have a `ToList()` method. Try moving `ToList()` down a line, after the `}`.

Comment: @gunr2171 it would give him an `IEnumerable<List<AnonymousType>>`

Comment: @Selman22 As in your answer, you need to wrap the query and call ToList on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `ToList` on your query not the decimal property, also you need parentheses around the query:

```
 (from line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Skip(1)
             let columns = line.Split(',')
             select new DailyValues
             {
                 Date = DateTime.Parse(columns[0]),
                 Open = decimal.Parse(columns[1]),
                 High = decimal.Parse(columns[2]),
                 Low = decimal.Parse(columns[3]),
                 Close = decimal.Parse(columns[4]),
                 Volume = decimal.Parse(columns[5]),
                 AdjClose = decimal.Parse(columns[6])
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<DailyValues> values = 
    (
         from line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Skip(1)
         let columns = line.Split(',')
         select new DailyValues
         {
             Date = DateTime.Parse(columns[0]),
             Open = decimal.Parse(columns[1]),
             High = decimal.Parse(columns[2]),
             Low = decimal.Parse(columns[3]),
             Close = decimal.Parse(columns[4]),
             Volume = decimal.Parse(columns[5]),
             AdjClose = decimal.Parse(columns[6])
         }
    ).ToList();
```

1. You need to make a list out of the entire query
2. You don't need to create a new List and then overwrite it